# Route to component and change some values of that component

Tags: angular, routes

I have two component in my Angular website, in my second component I have a function:

```
 this.ben = 1;

  send(){
    var param = JSON.stringify({'beneficiari': this.ben});
    console.log("JSON",param);
    this.http.post("", param).subscribe((res)=>{
    if (JSON.stringify(res as string)){
      console.log("RESP", res);
    }
    },(error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
}
```

and in my first I have a button which should open the second component and execute the send() function changing "this.ben", how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should provably use a service for that send method, so you can inject it and call for either component. That way you can parametrize the route for your second component and get it from the [ActiveRoute's ParamMap observable](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-parammap-observable-for-handling-route-in-angular/), and simply use a routerLink for your button. Also, you don't need any of those `JSON.stringify` with Angular's [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http).

Answer (score 0):

In your first component add

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;
...
ngOnInit() { 
   this.child.send();
}
```

Regards

Comment: Does it work even if SecondoComponent is not a child of the first?